# Can I skip all the checkpoints in Shovel Knight by jumping over them?

Tags: shovel-knight

Can I skip a checkpoint without destroying it by jumping over it on level ground? I tried with the first few checkpoints in the game and at some point during the arc I dipped too low and triggered the checkpoint.

Edit: as mentioned in an answer below, not all checkpoints are the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can, though I've not been able to do it without the help of the Gear relic (from about halfway through).

Certain stages actually provide alternate paths that may bypass checkpoints entirely (the checkpoint before the first Gryphon in King Knight's stage come to mind), meaning you have to backtrack a bit if you want to trigger the respawn.

May I ask why you're trying to not-trigger but not-destroy the checkpoints in the first place? Is it just for the added challenge?

Comment: The checkpoints in the first level cannot be destroyed, so I was curious if it was possible to avoid them this way with better jumping skills.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your regular jumping height is enough to clear a standard checkpoint.  You just need to make sure that you jump soon enough so you don't clip the orb.

I've recorded a quick video jumping over one of them.  You don't need any special armor or relics for this, you just have to get the timing down.

Do note that the checkpoints in the first stage of the game (Plains) have larger hit boxes (due to the wingy things around the orb) so you probably won't be able to for those.

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling because I was trying to do this for the ones in the first level. Why "probably" though? Seems like strange wording if it's not possible to jump that high.

Comment: FYI, your video appears to be private now.

Comment: @ChrisHayes ah, naturally, YT changed it to private some time ago. Should be back now.

Comment: Yup, working for me. Thanks for a speedy fix.